# Angular.js:10671 TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular by following a course, and I don't have much experience in javascript. I just can't seem to get ng-class to work and can't see why am I getting in the title mentioned error. 
This is my hotels.js file:

```
 'use strict'

 //MODULE
 var app = angular.module('hotelsApp', ['ngRoute']);

 app.controller('HotelsController', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.rooms = mockRooms;

 $scope.promoted = function(room) {
  if(room.promotion !== null && room.promotion !== undefined) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
 }

$scope.booking = function(room){
  if(room.beds>1){
    alert(room.size + " with " + room.beds + " beds, is booked");
  }
  else
    alert(room.size + " with " + room.beds + " bed, is booked");
};

}]);

var mockRooms = [{
  "size": "studio",
  "beds": 2,
  "number": 100,
  "kitchen": true,
  "price": "100$",
  "booked": false, 
  "promotion" : {
      "discount" : "30%",
      "message" : "Reserve it today!",
      "price" : "70$"
  }    
},
{ "size": "queen",
  "beds": 2,
  "number": 101,
  "kitchen": true,
  "price": "35$",
  "booked": true }      
];
```

And this is my index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-us" ng-app="hotelsApp">
 <head>
 <title>Hotels app</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/main.css" />
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HotelsController">
  <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    <h4>{{ room.size }}</h4>
    <p>Beds: {{ room.beds }}</p>
    <p>Room number: {{ room.number }}</p>
    <p ng-show="room.kitchen">
    Kitchen available
    </p>
    <p ng-hide="room.promotion">
    Price: {{ room.price }}
    </p>
    <p ng-class="{heavy:promoted(room)}" ng-hide="!room.promotion">
    Save {{ room.promotion.discount }} {{ room.promotion.message }} Price: {{ room.promotion.price }}
    </p>
    <button ng-hide="room.booked" ng-click="booking(room)">Book now!</button>
 </div>

 <script src="app/hotels/hotels.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Everything else except ng-class works as expected?

Comment: yes, everything else works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Correct these lines. Your links are all broken:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/main.css" />
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js">   </script>
```

Kindly put "https://" infront of all cdn's.

Use these cdn's:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
> ```

[image]

Comment: I did as you said, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Bro see my snapshot. I think you want this only ?

Comment: I want it to apply class .heavy to p element and that is not happening even when I use your cdn's

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake, if I change in the link to main.css, src to href, everything works fine. Just not sure why the console throw an error of undefined property before, that confused me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, this question got me. 
Please replace `src` with `href` in `link` tag for loading your custom css and try reloading the page.

Everything is right except your css is not loading.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my answer I saw that that was the mistake, just not sure why console first throw that error, and later everyhting worked just fine.